# NSPredicate and NSArray of ALAssets

Tags: ios, filter, nspredicate, alasset

I have NSArray which contain all ALAssets from my library. I need filter it by names of this assets. I've tried create second array only with names of assets (via ALAssetRepresention). But then I can't show their thumbnails and save link to asset. 
So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all of the objects (like name, thumbnail and urls) in one object then store all those objects in one array. Then use this code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ItemTitle" 
                                                       ascending:YES 
                                                        selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

[arrData sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
```

I store names in object that contain NSString with name "ItemTitle"

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your idea. :( I don't need sort this items, I need filter it for search view.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem next way.
I create object `SearchItems` which contain 2 values: `NSString *name` and `ALAsset *asset`.
When I'm enumerating files from library, I set values:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];

SearchItem *newItem = [[SearchItem alloc] init];
[newItem setName:[rep filename]];
[newItem setAsset:result];
```

Then I add this item to my `NSMutableArray`:
`[assetsItems addObject:newItem];`

And at last I use NSPredicate to filter my array by `name`:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
    _searchResults = [self.assetsItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

And now array ready to fetch. Example with table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";

    SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SearchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    SearchItem *searchItem = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ALAsset *currentAsset = searchItem.asset;
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [currentAsset defaultRepresentation];

    [cell.nameLabel setText:[rep filename]];
    [cell.thumbnail setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[currentAsset thumbnail]]];

    return cell;
}
```

That's all. I hope it will help somebody in future.